# Data based on previous viewController, Class or rootViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have 4 seperate tableViews which, when selected do a modal segue to a tabBarController containing four tabs. Of those four tabs they all have a common tab which performs an XML parse.

Ive done some reading and it seems I have three ways of doing it.Either I can

A) Use a class to define where the data is coming from but I don't want to instantiate all the options

B) Find out what the current TabBarController is and use that as a condition

c) Find out where we segued from and use that data

Which would be the best way to perform this action, and how would I do it(the segue is working with data being passed). Please note that I am not using the UINavigationController.

I basically want to end up with a switch performing the functions based on where its coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use a singleton.

You could also create a data model and pass pointers to it to your various classes, as needed.

As for using a switch, just setup your data with an index of some sort, such as an array, and pull it based on the current tab bar object. If you plan to use `UITabBarController` then call its `selectedIndex` property to know which tab bar item is selected.

Comment: I looked into your suggestions and came to the following conclusions: The singleton looks interesting, Ive never heard of it before. I read found what looked to be good code at this url [link](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/). Would this be declared in the AppDelegate and how would one assign values to it?  Secondly I looked into using a data model, Im battling to figure out how to set and keep my values based on where I'm coming from as I'm segueing into a TabBarController.

Comment: That link is valid, there are other ways but they all essentially do the same thing, which is create a single instance of a data model and prevent the accidental creation of multiple instances, then allow easy access to that data model from any class, typically through a class method not an instance method. You could create the singleton in App Delegate or any other class that loads at launch time, or you could wait to have it created when it is actually needed.

Comment: Your questions are actually many questions on basic programming techniques and I think at this point what you need is to read a good book on objective C such as this one: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0672325861/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0672325861&linkCode=as2&tag=andspag-20

Comment: I have already bought and read that book, the problem that Im having is beyond the scope of it and is a specific technical issue. However I understand that I lack the technical jargon to explain my situation. Thank you for your help anyway. I will do some more research and come back with a clearer explanation.

Comment: It would help us if you post actual code so we know where to assist you better